# Invalid tool ID 2.2 on jenkins gradle automatic install how to resolve?

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to setup `jenkins` for android gradle build.  So in `manage jenkins --> configure system --> gradle --> gradle installations` I set these values

```
gradle <-- name
Yes <-- install automatically
2.2 <-- version
```

in my jenkins build project:

`build --> invoke gradle script --> gradle version: "gradle", tasks: "clean build"`

When I run my build it fails with message:

```
Checking out Revision 7c2d53cc5df5a48695b0828f18de0573d072dd60 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 7c2d53cc5df5a48695b0828f18de0573d072dd60
 > git rev-list 7c2d53cc5df5a48695b0828f18de0573d072dd60 # timeout=10
[Gradle] - Launching build.
Invalid tool ID 2.2
[Gradle] - [ERROR] Can't retrieve the Gradle executable.
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Am I doing wrong? is this a [bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27310?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel)? how can I fix this to work please?

Comment: Can you find out the suggested in jenkins jira? What have you inside that directory?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I'm stuck on this and not seeing any solutions on SO or Google.

Comment: @ShatyUT I don't quite remember but from what I can recollect I first downloaded gradle and then defined a new `gradle` in jenkins to point to it - it worked.  then I think i had restarted jenkins, and tried again with original gradle and it worked, so it might just be that restart worked (and if not install a custom gradle and point to it).

Comment: hmm, thanks for responding. I've restarted and uninstalled gradle plugin a ton of times and tried different versions to download via configure system with no luck. Maybe I'll post my own question.

Comment: @ShatyUT on the meantime are you interested in the workaround of installing `gradle` separately and pointing jenkins to that variable? (i used that until things suddenly worked! which was only a few hours after using that workaround).

Comment: I ended up getting it working by changing my jenkins job to use the Gradle wrapper instead of specific Gradle version. I had found some post where someone said to try executing ./gradlew assemble on the command line. I did that and saw it pull down Gradle and build successfully. That made me think about switching the job setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same problem. The list of Gradle versions was not being shown.

The file JENKINS_HOME/updates/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstaller should contain the list of installations. For some reason it was not populated.

In order to populate/update this file go to:

Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced: Click "Check Now" button at the bottom/right of the page.

Source: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27310

Comment: I had a similar issue recently, Jenkins job failing because it was failing to download Groovy (as I had configure in **Global Tool Configuration**). Looking in the console the download URL was incorrect:  `https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/dist-release-local/groovy-zips/pache-groovy-binary-2.4.9.zip` -  pache-groovy-binary-2.4.9.zip instead of  **a**pache-groovy-binary-2.4.9.zip. Clicking **Check Now** as you suggested resolved this incorrect download url also.